# Spring, Infinispan and JGroups - configuration programmatically

Tags: spring, caching, config, infinispan, jgroups

I am using Spring 4.3, Infinispan 9.11 and JGroups 4.0.6. For JGroups I am using xml configuration, in which I have:

```
<TCPPING async_discovery="true"
         initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts: HOSTS}"
(...)
```

Let's say I want to keep configuration in xml, however, I need to apply a list of hosts from another (yml) configuration file. A way to go might be to read yml properties from Java (I have that part) and set them somehow to the JGroups configuration.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(
            GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()
                    .transport()
                    .nodeName(nodeName)
                    .addProperty(JGroupsTransport.CONFIGURATION_FILE, "tcp.xml")
                    .addProperty(JGroupsTransport.CONFIGURATION_STRING, "jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts: HOSTS")
                    .build(),
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    ...
                    .build()
    );
```

However, configuration string doesn't do the job.

UPDATE. Another attempt:

```
JGroupsTransport transport = (JGroupsTransport)(cacheManager.getCacheManagerConfiguration().transport().transport());
    TCPPING ping = transport.getChannel().getProtocolStack().findProtocol(TCPPING.class);
    ping.setPortRange(1);
    ping.setInitialHosts(Arrays.asList(new IpAddress("HOST1:PORT1"), new IpAddress("HOST2:PORT2")));
```

That doesn't seem to be working neither.

Comment: Oops, you're right; the channel has already joined the cluster, so setting initial_hosts is done too late at this time! Hmm, you need to do this before JChannel.connect() is called, but I don't know when Infinispan calls connect()... perhaps worth asking this question on the Infinispan mailing list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bela Ban and Altanis indicated, the problem is that Infinispan is calling JChannel.connect() before I am able to modify the transport properties. I've found a workaround though:

```
public class JGroupsChannelLookupImpl implements JGroupsChannelLookup {

    @Override
    public JChannel getJGroupsChannel(Properties p) {
        JChannel channel = null;
        try {
            channel = new JChannel("tcp.xml");
            TCPPING ping = channel.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(TCPPING.class);
            ping.setInitialHosts(Arrays.asList(HOST1, HOST2, HOST3, ...));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // do sth with the ex
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull(channel);
        return channel;
    }

(...)

}
```

Then when creating DefaultCacheManager, instead of loading the config directly from xml, just load channel lookup:

```
new DefaultCacheManager(
            GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()
                    .transport()
                    .nodeName(nodeName)
                    .addProperty(JGroupsTransport.CHANNEL_LOOKUP, JGroupsChannelLookupImpl.class.getName())
                    .build(),
           (...)
```

Works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the JGroups JChannel, you can grab TCPPING like so: `channel.getProtocolStack().findProtocol(TCPPING.class)` and then invoke the setter to set initial_hosts on it.

Comment: Hello! Yes, but I'm not entirely sure how I can retrieve JChannel object in my case. I don't want to create second channel (next to the one created from xml config).

Answer (score 0):

Before digging into Infinispan internals, let me try the easy path.

Do you know all the hosts on application boot time? If so, you can use environmental variable (or a system property) to inject the list of hosts. Just execute `java myApp -Djgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts=host1..`.

The other way to do it is to dig into Infinispan internals just like you did. The only problem is that your implementation does this too late (JGroups channel is already initialized at that point). So you would need to inject a view (probably using an `INJECT_VIEW` protocol, see the [manual](http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/#INJECT_VIEW))

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sounds good, but unfortunately the convention I need to stick to is to have a list of hosts in .yml properties file

Comment: That should still be fine. Just read that fine before booting up Spring and use System.setProperty to set application properties. Sounds like a work around but I that's way easier approach than injecting views manually.

Comment: Yes, but I still need to figure out how to inject these properties to JGroups. That seems to be the tricky part..